# extracting data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following data

```
set.seed(123)

a <- c(rep(1,30),rep(2,30))
b <- rep(1:30)
c <- sample(20:60, 60, replace = T)
data <- data.frame(a,b,c)
data
```

Now I want to extract data whereby:

For each unique value of `a`, extract/match data where the `b` value is the same and the `c` value is within a limit of +-5

so a desired output should produce:

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing a word here

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the desired out put, but are you looking for `data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(abs(b - c) <= 5)`?

Comment: so here, a equals 1 or 2. Where a=1, assess all cases where a=2, and extract so that the b value is the same, and the c value is within +-5 limit

Comment: Please use `set.seed` in order to make your question reproducible and provide desired output

Comment: using something similiar to this: data2 <- data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(b)==1 & abs(c - c) <= 5)

Comment: You can't use `group_by(a)` here because you are comparing between two `a` groups. Something like `data %>% group_by(b) %>% filter(abs(diff(c)) <= 5)` seem to work for your data

Comment: You only have two `a` group in your data?

Comment: yes it is a treat/control variable

Comment: Ok, posted as an answer so this question will be abswered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to compare *within* each distinct `b` group (as they are unique within each `a`), thus you should group by `b`. It is also not possible to group by `a` and compare *between* them, thus a possible solution would be

```
data %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  filter(abs(diff(c)) <= 5)
```

with `data.table` package this would be something like

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[abs(diff(c)) <= 5], b]
```

Or

```
data[, if (abs(diff(c)) <= 5) .SD, b]
```

Or

```
data[data[, abs(diff(c)) <= 5, b]$V1]
```

In base R it would be something like

```
data[with(data, !!ave(c, b, FUN = function(x) abs(diff(x)) <= 5)), ]
```